# Using LocalForage with angular 4

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-material2, localforage

I have a list of items (using angular material2) that can be toggled and when opened/closed I want to save the state in localstorage.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ckk4BCkNYNgNzJodW53t?p=preview

I have no clue why but [expanded] runs multiple times..

html

```
<md-expansion-panel class="panel"  (opened)="openPanel('a3')" (closed)="closePanel('a3')">
```

js

```
shouldBeExpanded(name: string) {
   let item = localStorage.getItem(name);
   return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but it does the job.
By using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` I can get the result I want.. but I will probably rework this later on and amongst other things I´ll update the solution to similar approach as @Nehal wrote.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3daXShLOilqhUA4J7eo?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are doing a function binding with `[expanded]`. So, every time change detection runs, it's going over the `shouldBeExpanded` function again and again.

**Option 1:**

If you want to keep using `shouldBeExpanded` for [expanded] flag, you can use the `OnPush` change detection strategy.

When I tested this, the expansion and collapse was little glitchy. Try it out in the demo

ts:

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pUgycrZkvpFXDjLoFept?p=info)

**Option 2:**

Instead of binding with a function, you can create an array that keeps track of the flag for each expansion. You can initialize the array using `OnInit` with the values stored in `localstorage`. If value is not in localstorage, you can assign a default flag. Whenever the expansion state changes, update it in the array and `localstorage`.

ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInt {

  private version: any;

  items = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
  expansionFlag = [];

  constructor(http: Http) {
    // Display the currently used Material 2 version.
    this.version = http
      .get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/material2-builds/commits/HEAD')
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    for(let i = 0; i <this.items.length; i++){
      let flag = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.items[i]));
      console.log(flag);
      if(flag != undefined && flag != null){
        this.expansionFlag.push(flag);
      }
      else
        this.expansionFlag.push(false);
    }

    console.log(this.expansionFlag)
  }
  openPanel(name, index) {
    console.log(name, 'is now open')
    this.expansionFlag[index] = true;
    localStorage.setItem(name, 'true');
  }
  closePanel(name, index) {
    console.log(name, 'is now closed');
    this.expansionFlag[index] = false;
    localStorage.setItem(name, 'false');
  }

}
```

Update each `[expanded]` in the html:

```
[expanded]="expansionFlag[0]"
[expanded]="expansionFlag[1]"
[expanded]="expansionFlag[2]"
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1aB0jGht7RNP4zRKQlj9?p=preview)